# Getting the ListView to reload it's Views

Tags: android, listview, reload

The situation:
I have an activity with a spinner and a list with a `BaseAdapter`.

The list is loaded once, and shows correctly... But when I click on the spinner to change the underlying data and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` the list doesn't refresh.

By this I mean that the data is changed and the adapter has the right data, it's just that the listView doesn't change the view.

How to force the listViews to show the right data?

Comment: after calling notifyDataSetChanged(), you should be seeing your adapters getView() called for each visible row.  If you're using the "contentView" and not resetting the values, you won't see the values update unless you scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Try `adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();` as well as `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`</s>

---

**EDIT:**
Clear your ArrayList or whatever you're using before you add more items with something like `.clear();` and then add the new items and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: only notifyDataSetChanged() is really needed

Comment: Just tried this doesn't work, I get the old list + randomly (?) inserted rows. Don't really understand the logic behind it.
And just the notifyDataSetChanged() doesnt change anything at all.

Comment: Why does it not work if I do this profil_array = new ArrayList<Profil>(); instead of profil_array.clear() ?

Comment: I don't know without seeing the source code. Does it work now?

Comment: There's alot of code, and I haven't got the time to post it today, but tomorrow i'll edit the first post and paste the relevant parts of it and would appreciate some critics, because I think I'm probably getting the "big picture" wrong.

Comment: If it works atm, then you could accept my answer and start a new question tomorrow. I'll take a look then too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
myListView.invalidateViews();
```

Comment: This has the same result has Todd Davies answer